# Python 3's encode() and decode() methods

Tags: python

In Python 3 there are `str` and `bytes` types. To convert a `bytes` type into a `str` type, one would call the decode() method on an instance and vice versa. I am confused as to why this is, why is it not encode()? As I understand it, internally the actual bytes in memory are being encoded into an encoding (UTF-8 in Python's case).

Comment: You can think of encode/decode as serialise/deserialise of unicode objects (which is the `str` type in Python3)

Comment: By far the best introduction to this subject is [Ned Batchelder](http://pyvideo.org/speaker/140/ned-batchelder)'s PyCon 2012 lecture, "[Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://pyvideo.org/video/948/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain)" ([on You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bytes *are* the encoding. You need to decode them in order to get the text they encode. How Python encodes the text as bytes internally is... not your problem.